# Swift check if core data objects allSatisfy a predicate

Tags: swift

I have fetchedResultsController that uses an entity named `Convo`. I am trying to check if the fetched objects all satisfy a given predicate on tap of a button like this...

```
    if fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.allSatisfy(){
            print("All objects have been read")
        }else{
            print("All objects have not been read")
        }
```

But I am unsure how to enter `isRead` as the `allSatisfy()` parameter argument. My `Convo` entity has these attributes

[image: attributes].

I would like to check for `isRead` .

Comment: I've never worked with CoreData before, but I think you might want to do this filtering with an `NSPredicate` instead. AFAIK, CoreData will parse the predicate and implement a query that does the filtering on the DB side, as opposed to this, which loads a lot of objects and filters them in the app after the DB has loaded them

Comment: @Alexander ok i will try that out